# Problema con Web Service tipo Soap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net, vb.net

Estoy tratando de consumir un Web Service SOAP desde un Ajax pero al invocar dicho Ajax algo falla. ¿Qué puedo hacer? El Web Service se encuentra alojado en un servidor IIS con la siguiente ruta.

http://iis:8888/WebServices.asmx?op=ActualizarPassword

cuando ejecuto esta ruta en el navegador desde mi equipo se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al ejecutar la misma ruta desde el servidor IIS se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La petición Ajax que estoy ejecutando es la siguiente:

```js
$('#btnAceptar').on('click', function () {
                if (Validar() === false) {
                    $.post("http://iis:8888/WebServices.asmx/ActualizarPassword", { claveAntigua: $("#txtClave").val(), claveNueva: $("#txtClaveNueva").val(), nit: $("#nitUsuario").val() })
                        .done(function (resultado) {
                            num = resultado
                            var respuesta = parseInt(num.documentElement.textContent)
                            if (respuesta >= 1) {
                                toastr.success('Su contraseña fue actualizada correctamente');
                                Limpiar();
                            } else {
                                toastr.error('No se ha podido actualizar la información.');
                                Limpiar();
                            }

                        }).fail(function (resultado) {
                            toastr.error('Hubo un error en el sistema, intente de nuevo más tarde.');
                            Limpiar();
                        });
                }
            });
```

Y tengo una `ServiceReference` referenciando la url del `IIS` así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado también poner en la ruta de la petición la url del servidor http://iis:8888/WebServices.asmx?op=ActualizarPassword pero tampoco funciona.

Al ejecutar la petición se va por el fail de la petición y sale un **error 500**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier aporte me ayudará mucho para conocer cuál es el problema el cual se está presentando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando publicas un WS en IIS no te va a mostrar los parámetros, ésto solo lo muestra localmente, no implica que no podas consumir tu servicio web.

El error 500, se muestra porque tu servicio web está caído.

El motivo por el que no te consume el servicio web puede ser porque que tu WS no tiene los parámetros de configuración en el web.config.

Pon los siguientes parámetros de configuración de protocolos en el web.config de tu WS y nos cuentas como te va.

```html
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, realice la configuración que menciono en la respuesta y se corrigio el problema.